# How to know the full request has been received with HTTP 1.0 and HTTP 1:1?

Tags: http

I'm implementing a ultra simple dummy HTTP server responding a message with Hello world to any requests. It is just for benchmarking the asynchronous event handling with `wrk` or equivalent web server benchmarking tool.

After some searching on the Web I can't find a clear EndOfMessage (EOM) marker. It seam that with HTTP 1.0 we know we have received the full request when the connection is closed. Is that right ?

For HTTP 1.1, how do we know if pipelining is used ? What is the EOM in this case ?

Comment: You've [read the RFC](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616), right?

Comment: @tadman I wanted to avoid reading these 176 pages. From this page http://www.the-art-of-web.com/system/telnet-http11/ the GET request should be ended in a blanc line, thus "\r\n\r\n". But other request methods may have a message body, etc.  Is this also the case with HTTP 1.0 ? I'm not interested in the request message content.

Comment: @tadman: the RFC is 7230, not 2616. Also, the relevant part is really small, see https://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc7230.html#message.body.length

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> After some searching on the Web I can't find a clear EndOfMessage (EOM) marker.

You can't find one because such a thing doesn't exist. The only marker you *may* find is the `CRLF` pair indicating the end of the header fields. In general, the enclosed entity length (that is for requests **and** responses!) is either communicated beforehand via the `Content-Length` header or through the transport coding.

> with HTTP 1.0 we know we have received the full request when the connection is closed. Is that right?

That is one of two ways mandated by RFC 1945. So generally speaking: no. From [RFC 1945, section 7.2.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-7.2.2):

> When an Entity-Body is included with a message, the length of that body may be determined in one of two ways. If a [`Content-Length`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1945#section-10.4) header field is present, its value in bytes represents the length of the Entity-Body. *Otherwise, the body length is determined by the closing of the connection by the server.*

This may read like you were generally in the right with your assertion. **BUT:**

> Closing the connection *cannot be used to indicate the end of a request body*, since it leaves no possibility for the server to send back a response.

With you being on the receiving side, your assumption is simply wrong on every conceivable level: If the request contains a body, announcing the size of said body through the `Content-Length` header is an *absolute requirement*.

HTTP/1.1 is a bit relaxed in this regard, as it allows for more options. As Julian pointed out, please consult [RFC 7230, section 3.3.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-3.3.3). That section is straightforward to read and to answer your question, I'd have to c&p it as whole.

> For HTTP 1.1, how do we know if pipelining is used ?

You do if you receive multiple requests through one connection. The strongest indicator for the client non engaging into pipelining is the presence of `Connection: close` in the first received request. See [RFC 7230, section 6.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.3) and [section 6.3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7230#section-6.3.2). If you are worried about having to support this, you are always free to just read the first request and send back a response with `Connection: close` in it. The client will know it has to establish a new connection.

> What is the EOM in this case ?

Again, there is no marker as there is no special treatment for requests during pipelining. All pipelining is really enabling is to have multiple requests being issued in one go. See section 3.3.3 from above on how to determine the message length.